# Why am I crashing and getting the wrong day of the week?

Tags: c#, datagridview, switch-statement, datagridviewrow

My system clock is 9/16/2014 (Tuesday)

But in code, I'm always jumping to Monday.

```
DayOfWeek dow = new DateTime().DayOfWeek;
int columnNumber = 0;

columnNumber = columnNumber + 0;

foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows )
{
  switch ( dow )
  {
  case DayOfWeek.Monday:
    columnNumber = 4;
    if ( (bool) row.Cells[4].Value == true ) // crashing here with NullReferenceException
    {
      row.Cells["activeTodayDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn"].Value = true;
    }
    break;
```

I have a `DataGridView`

- Columns 0—3 are `Text`
- Columns 4—9 are `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

Comment: I answered one question.  You should ask one question per, uh, question.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) next time. One of the very first examples for `DateTime` shows that `new DateTime()` defaults to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.` Or even just using your debugger. Wouldn't take much effort to notice that the `DateTime` object you're creating isn't today's date.

Comment: Not to be mean, but [your code smells](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatementsSmell). You should probably try using LINQ, [rather than **if**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554180/why-is-the-if-statement-considered-evil).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new DateTime()` isn't providing today's date, but the default value for `DateTime`

You want to change that line to :

`DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;`