# Crashing when trying to see if my Cell is checked or unchecked

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

My system clock is 9/16/2014 (Tuesday)

But in code, I'm always jumping to Monday.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
int columnNumber = 0;

columnNumber = columnNumber + 0;

foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows )
{
  switch ( dow )
  {
  case DayOfWeek.Monday:
    columnNumber = 4;
    if (Int32.Parse(row.Cells[columnNumber].Value.ToString()) == 1)
    {
         row.Cells["activeTodayDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn"].Value = true;
    }
    break;
```

I have a `DataGridView`

- Columns 0—3 are `Text`
- Columns 4—9 are `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

Comment: why dont you check if the cell is not null before checking it is true?

Comment: you just ask few mints ago same question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874523/why-am-i-crashing-and-getting-the-wrong-day-of-the-week

Comment: int columnNumber = 0;

columnNumber = columnNumber + 0;  ??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad someone pointed out that it was 2 questions in 1 posting so the code had very small changes but the problem is the same. Crashing on a cell.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect what I tried. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try to insert

```
if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
```

between foreach and switch

Comment: What will IsNewRow do? The data is already loaded on the screen when accessing the contents.

Comment: It's always returning false so we go to the switch and crash

Comment: IsNewRow returns true for the empty row at the bottom of the grid ... it's sometimes important to check because there rows[].Cells[].Value will be null

Comment: This is happening on the very first row, 2nd row, third row. If I check the box then uncheck it, it doesn't appear to crash