# How to handle the "else" clause when converting an "if..elif..else" statement into a dictionary lookup?

Tags: python, if-statement, technical-debt

I am trying to convert an "if else" statement in python into a dictionary.

I tried to convert it into a dictionary, but how do I handle the last else clause?

```
val=3

if val==1:
  print "a"
elif val==2:
  print "b"
elif val==3:
  print "c"
elif val==4:
  print "d"
else:
  print "value not found:"

print "===========Converted if else into dictionary ==================="

DATA_SOURCE = {1:"a",2:"b",3:"c",4:"d"}
print DATA_SOURCE[val]
```

I have created this code as a replacement:

```
if not DATA_SOURCE.has_key(val):
  print "value not found:"
else:
  print DATA_SOURCE[val]
```

Is it equivalent?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to eliminate if/else?

Comment: @Thecheater887 may be to reduce the number of coding lines

Comment: @Thecheater887 See [Why is the 'if' statement considered evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554180/why-is-the-if-statement-considered-evil)

Comment: Your `has_key` condition can be written as `val not in DATA_SOURCE`. I prefer this way.

Comment: Wow. Go here and get attacked. That was great! I forgot why I left SO, but now I think I rememeber..

Comment: @Thecheater887 it is a place to learn mate not a place to get attacked and happy learning

Comment: @Thecheater887 I thought you'd find the question and answers interesting. Really didn't mean it as an attack )c:

Comment: @VigneshKalai The struggle of being looked down upon because of my rep, and answering bluntly, but correctly rather than a general 'figure it out by yourself and come back later' is real much. Very few people are like you that they give a response to a question without bringing their flamethrowers, and I appreciate that. 

--Can I give you a cookie?

Comment: @PeterWood SO is a place of learning, and I just learned being blunt with a blunt person hurts a lot more than I remembered. Bridges are mended. ((Now back on topic..))

Comment: @Thecheater887 yeah a cookie would be nice :P and I too have been  in the same position  reputation does not matter learn from what is thrown at you and Peter wood did throw a valuable piece of gold

Comment: @VigneshKalai That depends on the eyes of the person that sees it. Someone might see it as gold, while others, like I, see it as an attack.. I guess it's time that I should upgrade the `perspective` module to v0.0.2 :P

Comment: @Thecheater887 verion v0.0.2 it is .The question which you asked was very elementary to some people  and what peter wood gave was a very valuable information even I did not know that :P. Just enjoy learning and  move forward

Comment: @Thecheater887 I hope you stick around. I didn't expect to be seen as blunt. Articles about removing conditionals from code have really helped my thinking about design. I just responded to your question with a relevant SO link. See [Unconditional Programming](http://michaelfeathers.typepad.com/michael_feathers_blog/2013/11/unconditional-programming.html), and [When A Method Can Do Nothing](https://michaelfeathers.silvrback.com/when-it-s-okay-for-a-method-to-do-nothing) from the great [Michael Feathers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052). Peace.

Comment: Not that I personally care too much which answer you selected, but why did you pick the more complicated, less pythonic one? This might be confusing to future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for;

```
val = 3
dct = {1:"a", 2:"b", 3:"c", 4:"d"}
if dct.get(val) == None: print "Value Not Found"
```

Comment: But a nice thing about `dict.get` is that you *don't* have to perform this kind of comparison.

Comment: @juanchopanza I understand why I got the downvote now.. I didn't before because it fails when I try it in my interpreter, or in cmd.

Comment: Interesting. Which one fails? Also, which python version?

Comment: `DATA_SOURCE.get(<stuffs>)` with `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'` and python 2.7.10.

Comment: But `DATA_SOURCE` is a `dict`, not a `set`.

Comment: Precisely. That's why I'm stumped. It may just be because I get near a computer and it tries to die on me..

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `dict.get` method:

```
print DATA_SOURCE.get(val, "value not found")
```

That will return `"value not found"` if `val` is not a key, without affecting the dictionary.

As always, if in doubt, use the help:

```
>>> help(dict)
```