# Why are nullable ForeignKeys "evil"?

Tags: database-design

Some time ago someone told me that nullable ForeignKeys are "evil" database design?

In other words it is an "anti-pattern", something you should avoid.

Why?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic please elaborate why are they not "evil"?

Comment: Because they model a common and useful case (_optional_ reference). I'm not aware of a better way to model that case. Are you?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic For places where we used nullable ForeignKeys in the past, we now use a default. Example: User---Country: We insert a country called "Unknown". If the country of a user is unknown this gets used as FK.

Comment: How do you know the "Unknown" row is special? Hard-code it in the business logic? And what values do you use for the other fields of the "Unknown" row? For example, what is a sensible country code, or a phone number of an "Unknown" country? What you describe is _a_ solution, but I wouldn't call it a _better_ solution.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic we don't have a phone number of our countries in our model. But you are right here, if we would have one. The "unknown" value now is in the phone-number. Did I say it was "better"? Then I am sorry ("Out beyond ideas of wrongdoing and rightdoing,
there is a field. I'll meet you there."). I would call my solution "an other strategy".

Answer (score 0):

You need an "if" to process a datastructure which has a nullable ForeignKey.

You can read more about why "if" is evil here: [Why is the 'if' statement considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554180/why-is-the-if-statement-considered-evil)

Comment: There is no `if` in SQL and you certainly don't need one to select rows with nullable foreign keys.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course you are right: There is no "if" in SQL. But in any programming language you need to decide: "Does this variable contain data or is it NULL".

Comment: And how is this specific to foreign keys? Other columns can be null as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, other columns could be nullable as well. .... I think the same rule applies. Handling nullable columns in a programming language is annoying.